# how to input value to webpage form using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to input a value from Excel to a webpage. I figured out all the way to opening the page and able to input values but the problem is there is one form that I could not figure out. Most of the forms have a tag, class, or a name but there are a few that does not seem to have it for me to identify in the code. Here is the webpage snippet of the form:

```
<div class="OrderForm_input">
    <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" placeholder="0.00" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <span>IDD</span>
</div>
```

I've searched around and this is the best I can come up with. I thought the tag here is "input" but that doesn't seem to work:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "\\HJInet\input"
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_input").getElementsByTagName("input").Value = "12.98"
```

I get an error on line 3: Run time error "438", Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_input")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "12.98"`

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes